# Facebook Page Like using Facebook Connect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way so that Facebook connect button could be used for liking facebook page too ?
Means If a user clicks on facebook connect button on my website then he automatically likes my page after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perfom multipule actions in a single plugin. Or Facebook are not allowing to perfom this type actions. You have to put [Facebook Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) to your site

Help Center -TheTricksLab.com